# Teradata Max per Partition with non-adjacent duplicates

Tags: duplicates, teradata, partition

Okay, this one might be a little tricky, so let me start with a visual.

Here's what the data looks like:
[Original Data From Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRumk.png)

I'm trying to simplify it so that it looks like this:
[End Result that I'm working towards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXLlK.png)

The problem is that I have an employee who changed back to a previous manager, so when I try to partition and group the data, those two instances get combined together and I end up with data that looks like this:
[Actual Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QulpQ.png)

In the image above we can see that Manager Tom has a Start and End Date that is within the Start and End date of Manager Bob which is an error. Any suggestions on how to isolate the grouping of a item that gets reintroduced at a later time? This would be determined by Start Date and Rank over Partition I believe, but I can't seem to get this to work.

Here's the query to build the sample data:

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE VT_AGENT
( 
EmpID INT
,Manager VARCHAR(16)
,Director VARCHAR(16)
,Record_Start DATE
,Record_End DATE
)  ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO vt_agent VALUES(12345678, 'Jill M.', 'Mike B.', '2019-08-21', '2019-09-07');
INSERT INTO vt_agent VALUES(12345678, 'Jill M.', 'Mike B.', '2019-09-07', '2019-09-16');
INSERT INTO vt_agent VALUES(12345678, 'Bob S.', 'Mike B.', '2019-09-16', '2019-10-15');
INSERT INTO vt_agent VALUES(12345678, 'Bob S.', 'Mike B.', '2019-10-15', '2019-11-23');
INSERT INTO vt_agent VALUES(12345678, 'Tom A.', 'Mike B.', '2019-11-23', '2019-12-07');
INSERT INTO vt_agent VALUES(12345678, 'Tom A.', 'Mike B.', '2019-12-07', '2019-12-12');
INSERT INTO vt_agent VALUES(12345678, 'Bob S.', 'Mike B.', '2019-12-12', '2020-01-15');
INSERT INTO vt_agent VALUES(12345678, 'Bob S.', 'Mike B.', '2020-01-15', '9999-12-31');

Select * FROM VT_AGENT
```

Comment: Generally I'd use normalize on this, but you've got a record for Bob S and Mike B that overlaps all other records for that combo, from 2019-01-15 thru 9999-12-31. In other words, I'd say your actual result is correct.

Comment: I'm guessing that last record was supposed to be `INSERT INTO vt_agent VALUES(12345678, 'Bob S.', 'Mike B.', '2020-01-15', '9999-12-31');`?

Comment: Yes, the 2019-01-15 was a typo. I manually retyped some data to further simplify the sample data and made a human error, good eye! The issue however is present with non-typo data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your last insert had the typos mentioned in the comments, you can make use of Teradata's Period data type (and functions) to make this super simple:

```
SELECT NORMALIZE 
   empid, 
   manager, 
   directory, 
   PERIOD(record_start, record_end) as valid_period 
FROM VT_AGENT;
```

What this is doing is constructing a PERIOD column type from the `record_start` and `record_end` dates. Then we use the `NORMALIZE` keyword to compress periods where all other non-period columns are equal across more than one record. The result is a single record with the expanded period. This works only when the periods in those matching records meet (the end of one stops at the start of the next) or overlap (the end of one is after the start of the next).

With the assumed typo corrected, this outputs:

```
+----------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
|  EmpID   | Manager | Director |       valid_period       |
+----------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
| 12345678 | Bob S.  | Mike B.  | (2019-09-16, 2019-11-23) |
| 12345678 | Bob S.  | Mike B.  | (2019-12-12, 9999-12-31) |
| 12345678 | Jill M. | Mike B.  | (2019-08-21, 2019-09-16) |
| 12345678 | Tom A.  | Mike B.  | (2019-11-23, 2019-12-12) |
+----------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
```